# query in MySQL to show each menu's submenu from wordpress database

Tags: wordpress

How to query in MySQL to show each menu's submenu from wordpress database.

**Actually I need sql query not php code**.

As like I have menu and it is like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may help.

```
select * from (select d.*,e.name,e.slug from(SELECT p.id,txr.term_taxonomy_id, p.post_title, p.post_name, p.menu_order, n.post_name as n_name, n.post_title as n_title, pp.meta_value as menu_parent,pt.meta_value as type
FROM wp_term_relationships as txr 
INNER JOIN wp_posts as p ON txr.object_id = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as m ON p.ID = m.post_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pl ON p.ID = pl.post_id AND pl.meta_key = '_menu_item_object_id' 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pp ON p.ID = pp.post_id AND pp.meta_key = '_menu_item_menu_item_parent'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pt ON p.ID = pt.post_id AND pt.meta_key = '_menu_item_object'
LEFT JOIN wp_posts as n ON pl.meta_value = n.ID 
WHERE p.post_status='publish' 
AND p.post_type = 'nav_menu_item' AND m.meta_key = '_menu_item_url' 
ORDER BY pp.meta_value) d
LEFT JOIN wp_terms as e on d.term_taxonomy_id=e.term_id) i where i.term_taxonomy_id = MENU ID
```